# View git changes/diffs of local commits not pushed to remote

Tags: git, git-commit, git-log

I have three `Git` commits that I committed locally, but have not pushed to GitHub. I would like to view the changes/diffs for all three commits, how do I view all the diffs?

I tried: `git log --branches --not --remotes`

Which shows me the three commits, but not all the diffs/changes of each.

```
commit c08fbb72ae6a06e8b2ff3dbbb96fb555a43f4136
Author: Justin <justin@mydomain.com>
Date:   Mon Sep 10 18:17:02 2012 -0700

    Updated order of requires in Requires.php

commit 041fe19a48269a8aea2ccf90f53568893d4e0158
Author: Justin <justin@mydomain.com>
Date:   Mon Sep 10 17:56:42 2012 -0700

    Checking for app.config.php in Requires.php

commit 61c103a8a122bcde2311d081a8340ee1dd71997c
Author: Justin <justin@mydomain.com>
Date:   Mon Sep 10 17:42:20 2012 -0700

    Version bump 0.4.0. See CHANGELOG.md
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: If you want to see the diff for each commit, use `git log -p --branches --not --remotes`.  The `-p` stands for patch.  It'll show you  unified diff for each commit.

Answer (score 18):

You could probably use git diff like this:

```
git diff origin/master..HEAD
```

assuming that your HEAD is currently pointing to your latest commit. Otherwise, you could just use

```
git diff origin/master..master
```

(Of course, change accordingly if your remote isn't origin, or if your branch isn't master.)

Answer (score 9):

`git log -p --branches --not --remotes`

Worked.

Comment: `git diff origin/master..HEAD` works if there haven't been any other commits to the remote branch since your last fetch. This solution works regardless of activity on the remote branch.  For that reason alone, I prefer this approach for viewing a diff of local commits not yet pushed.

Comment: This command does NOT list any diff details. It show only a list of commits with a diff inside.